# Function to return wordpress page data for Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, ecmascript-6, gatsby

I am trying to build a headless Wordpress Gatsby site. I want to write a function that fires a graphql query and returns the page data for Gatsby to consume.

So far I have this:

```
var GetPage = {
  graphql: ({ id }) => {
    `query GetPage {
        pages(where: {id: ` + id + `}) {
          edges {
            node {
              title
              content
              featuredImage {
                node {
                  uri
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }`
  }
}
```

This is failing with the error:

`5:5  error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

Is this the best approach? Am I handling this problem wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the error you're seeing and allow your **graphql** function to return the **GraphQL** query string that Gatsby can consume.

```js
var GetPage = {
  graphql: ({ id }) => {
    return `
      query GetPage {
        pages(where: {id: ${id}}) {
          edges {
            node {
              title
              content
              featuredImage {
                node {
                  uri
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
}
```